# Create a dataframe containing time spent in location based on a dataframe with trip information in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` that records the movement of people from one location to another. I would like to create a new dataframe `df2` that records the time when a location was entered and when the same location was left, based on the trip information in `df`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

current_time = '2022-05-05 17:00'

df = pd.DataFrame({"person_id": ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C"],
                   "start_location_id": [1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 8],
                   "end_location_id": [2, 6, 3, 8, 2, 9],
                   "start_ts": pd.to_datetime(["2022-05-05 00:00", "2022-05-05 00:00", "2022-05-05 05:00", "2022-05-05 00:00", "2022-05-05 13:00", "2022-05-05 11:00"]),
                   "end_ts": pd.to_datetime(["2022-05-05 02:00", "2022-05-05 03:00", "2022-05-05 10:00", "2022-05-05 04:00", "2022-05-05 16:00", "2022-05-05  12:00"]),
})
```

`df` would look like this:

```
print(df.to_string())
>>
  person_id  start_location_id  end_location_id            start_ts              end_ts
0         A                  1                2 2022-05-05 00:00:00 2022-05-05 02:00:00
1         B                  5                6 2022-05-05 00:00:00 2022-05-05 03:00:00
2         A                  2                3 2022-05-05 05:00:00 2022-05-05 10:00:00
3         C                  7                8 2022-05-05 00:00:00 2022-05-05 04:00:00
4         A                  3                2 2022-05-05 13:00:00 2022-05-05 16:00:00
5         C                  8                9 2022-05-05 11:00:00 2022-05-05 12:00:00
```

I then create `df2` using the following nested for loops. I would like to replace the code that sets up `df2` with code that uses pandas' groupby (or equivalent) functions. My current attempt is as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["person_id", "location_id", "enter_timestamp", "exit_timestamp"])

for i in np.unique(df["person_id"]):
    df3 = df.loc[df["person_id"] == i].reset_index(drop = True)
    for j in df3.index:
        try:
            df2 = df2.append({'person_id': i,
                              'location_id' : df3.loc[j, "end_location_id"],
                              'enter_timestamp' : df3.loc[j, "end_ts"],
                              'exit_timestamp' : df3.loc[j + 1, "start_ts"]}, ignore_index=True)
        except:
            df2 = df2.append({'person_id': i,
                          'location_id' : df3.loc[j, "end_location_id"],
                          'enter_timestamp' : df3.loc[j, "end_ts"]}, ignore_index=True)
```

My desired output would be:

```
print(df2.to_string())
>>
  person_id location_id     enter_timestamp      exit_timestamp
0         A           2 2022-05-05 02:00:00 2022-05-05 05:00:00
1         A           3 2022-05-05 10:00:00 2022-05-05 13:00:00
2         A           2 2022-05-05 16:00:00                 NaT
3         B           6 2022-05-05 03:00:00                 NaT
4         C           8 2022-05-05 04:00:00 2022-05-05 11:00:00
5         C           9 2022-05-05 12:00:00                 NaT
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sorting rows by column `person_id` by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then create column `exit_timestamp` with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), `rename` columns and for final expected columns filter them by list `cols`:

```
cols = ["person_id", "location_id", "enter_timestamp", "exit_timestamp"]
df = df.sort_values('person_id', ignore_index=True)
df['exit_timestamp'] = df.groupby('person_id')['start_ts'].shift(-1)
df = df.rename(columns={'end_location_id':'location_id', 'end_ts':'enter_timestamp'})[cols]
print (df)
  person_id  location_id     enter_timestamp      exit_timestamp
0         A            2 2022-05-05 02:00:00 2022-05-05 05:00:00
1         A            3 2022-05-05 10:00:00 2022-05-05 13:00:00
2         A            2 2022-05-05 16:00:00                 NaT
3         B            6 2022-05-05 03:00:00                 NaT
4         C            8 2022-05-05 04:00:00 2022-05-05 11:00:00
5         C            9 2022-05-05 12:00:00                 NaT
```